# Change font in Remote jupyter notebook

Tags: css, ssh, fonts, ipython, jupyter

I am accessing a jupyter notebook via ssh tunnel as explained here:
http://danielhnyk.cz/running-ipython-notebook-different-computer/

Unfortunately both chrome and firefox use the default font for the code cells of the remote notebook when I access it via http://localhost:8881/notebook.ipynb like in the attached screenshot
[image: Screenshot from firefox]

This is bad, since I want the code cells to be displayed in a fixed-width font.

I tried fixing it using the Font Changer extension for chrome, but this changes the font of the whole notebook to fixed-width, including the markdown cells, and it messes up the symbols in the Toolbar.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Note: When I run a notebook on my computer with the command  `jupyter notebook` the fonts look fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code font which I used on the notebook server was not installed on my home computer. I simply adapted the custom.css file under

```
.jupyter/custom/custom.css
```

to use a font installed on both machines, i.e. DejaVu Sans Mono:

```
.CodeMirror pre {
    font-family: DejaVu Sans Mono;
    font-size: 10pt;
}
```